# Methods for Groups and columns

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Can I force to put a group in the 2nd column another group?

What method should I choose?

Comment: What groups and columns is this question about?

Comment: Please describe the context.

Comment: You need to be more informative otherwise the answers are just tries to mindread you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean design and you want two design parts in one group next each other you need to set group property **Columns** from 1 to 2.